# launchd daemon can't connect to remote server

Tags: macos, terminal, network, command-line, launchd

I've developed a launchd daemon that updates my DNS on a remote server. That script used to work perfectly. On September 25th 2019 my logs began showing that there was a connection error with my remote server, but when I run the app in Terminal it works. Requests, a module for Python, returns the exception `ConnectionError` that could be a DNS resolution problem or network unavailability.

However, my network is available (it runs on Terminal) and I've also specified the `KeepAlive` tag `NetworkState` to true on my plist file, so that it only runs the script when the network is available.

```xml
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<dict>
    <key>NetworkState</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Was there an update that broke network connectivity for launchd? Are there new permissions for accessing remote servers? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Note: This script is running on macOS 10.13.6 and Python 3.7.5.

Comment: Excellent details. I always forget the debug file logging commands for these plist files - do you use a tool like https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/ to easily add stdout/ stderr to log to files? Sometimes it clearly lets you know the cause of the errors.

Comment: According to the man page for launchd.plist in macOS 10.13.6, "NetworkState <boolean> This key is no longer implemented as it never acted how most users expected." My guess is that the daemon is getting launched before the network stabilizes.

Comment: Thanks, @bmike! I haven't tested this yet. Do you think I may need to escape the URL I pass as ProgramArguments on my plist file?

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson. My script runs at startup and then every 30 minutes to check if the IP is still valid. So the network is definitely well stabilized when I am still getting connection errors.